# Can the absence of a class instance be used somehow?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've been messing about with stable names for a bit and want a function that checks for equivalence on the value level if an `Eq`-instance exists, but also on identity in general by using `StableName`. The following bit of code shows what I want to do, but this doesn't work because even with incoherent instances the given instances are duplicates:

```
import System.Mem.StableName

class Same a where
  equals :: a -> a -> IO Bool

instance Same a where
  equals = equalsStable

instance Eq a => Same a where
  equals = do
    b <- equalsStable x y
    return (x == y || b)

equalsStable :: a -> a -> IO Bool
equalsStable x y = do
  n1 <- makeStableName x
  n2 <- makeStableName y
  return (n1 == n2)
```

Is there a way to specifically select on non-instances of a class? Or is there some other way to make this code work?

Comment: The linked question asks about `Show` particularly, but for what you really want to know I believe this doesn't matter. A brief answer is: _no_, Haskell does by design not allow to check that a type is not an instance of some class, because there is no way to prove somebody won't add such an instance later on. IOW, the default assumption is _every type is an instance of **every** class_, though to actually _use_ an instance the compiler obviously needs to know where it is defined.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ok thank you. I missed that one when searching.

Comment: It's not just that someone might add an insurance later on, but there might already be an instance that is used in other modules of the same program, and merely isn't *visible* (not imported) rather than didn't exist. Unless we require that every other module in the final program is available for inspection when compiling each module, the compiler can't tell that situation apart from the instance actually not existing. So any decisions it makes based on not being able to see an instance could be made inconsistently in different modules; to prevent that, it just never makes any such decisions.

Comment: If I add `instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Eq a where x == y = False` I can just implement `equals` as a regular function. Which does exactly what I want (since I'm trying to lower false negatives, not eliminate them). However that pretty much ruins `Eq` everywhere else, so it would be nice if I could somehow encapsulate this.